# Thread error in delphi

Tags: database, multithreading, sqlite, delphi

I've written a search code to explore the database. Because the query acts alone, so I used the Thread.

Now this Thread (one of the users at the website is written) gives a lot of error.

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.QueryFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    // something went wrong 
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      MLog.Lines.Add('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);  /// MLog is Memo For Log
      MLog.Lines.Add('Exception message = '+E.Message);
    end;
    exit;
  end;
  MLog.Lines.Add('Search is Done!');
end;

procedure TForm1.Requery;
var
   Thread: TThread;
begin
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
      begin
        query.close;
        query.sql.text:='select * from Customer where CustomerID LIKE "%'+Form1.edit1.text+'%"';
        query.open;
      end);
  Thread.OnTerminate := QueryFinished;
  Thread.Start; 
end;
```

Error 1:

Project project1.exe raised exception class EEvaluatorError with message 'Couldn't find Text'

Erro 2:

Project project1.exe raised exception class EEvaluatorError with message 'EvalError in LinkControlToField6: Couldn't find Text'

Error 3:

Project project1.exe raised exception class EArgumentOutOfRangeException with message 'Argument out of range'

Error 4:

Project project1.exe raised exception class EBindCompError with message 'EvalError in LinkControlToField2: Access violation at address 5005FC08 in module 'rtl230.bpl' Read of address 000000D0'

Error 5:

Access Violation at address 006CE2BF in module 'FireDACCommon230.bpl' read of address 00000004

What can be done to solve this problem?

Maybe I should just Terminate my Thread.
How do I know that a Thread has Terminate right?

Comment: We know nothing `query`. [Mcve].

Comment: This won't work as you need to create the connection & query in the context of the thread. And don't use the form variable when you are already in the class itself...

Comment: Forget about the thread, what you need are async database operations (which will use a thread internally). Read the [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FireDAC.TFDQuery.Async_Sample)

Comment: The thread returns an error object with plenty of potentially useful information. Yet you ignore that info and simply report: `Form1.edit2.text:='!!ERROR!!';` Certainly that code didn't report any of the errors you've included in your question. So it seems unlikely the errors occur where you think.

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem but your assignments `Form1.edit2.text:=` are a bad idea, because they assume that the specific instance `Form1` of `TForm1` has been created and would cause an AV if it hasn't.  To fix, simply delete both occurrences of `Form1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up your search, you should use the Async method.

There are many examples in Delphi, for example, go to the following address to your computer:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDQuery\ExecSQL\Async
```

Run the project and take that pattern.

Or read links below:

[Asynchronous Execution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Asynchronous_Execution_(FireDAC))

[Cancel an Asynchronous](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=46311)